# Fossil: not authorized to write

Tags: fossil

What am I doing wrong? I realize I havent read up on any user management but I'm completely local here and never created any users myself so why wouldnt it work?

```
pc@pc-desktop:~/Desktop$ ./fossil test-hash-passwords test-fossil 
pc@pc-desktop:~/Desktop$ ./fossil server
Listening for HTTP requests on TCP port 8080


pc@pc-desktop:~/testcheckout$ ./fossil clone http://localhost:8080 bla
pc@pc-desktop:~/testcheckout$ ./fossil add .
current directory is not within an open checkout
pc@pc-desktop:~/testcheckout$ ./fossil open bla
pc@pc-desktop:~/testcheckout$ ./fossil add .
pc@pc-desktop:~/testcheckout$ ./fossil test-hash-passwords test-fossil 
pc@pc-desktop:~/testcheckout$ ./fossil push
Push to http://localhost:8080
Round-trips: 1   Artifacts sent: 0  received: 0
Error: not authorized to write
Round-trips: 1   Artifacts sent: 0  received: 0
Push finished with 385 bytes sent, 303 bytes received
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving that error because you do not have permissions to modify the remote repository. When you do not supply any credentials, your login name (`pc` in this case) is used and the `pc` user probably doesn't exist in the remote repository (or you'd have received a password prompt).

To make this work, you'll need to create an account on the *remote* repository and use those credentials while doing `fossil push`.

Comment: the command on the serverside is: "./fossil user new myusername contact@gmail.com mypw" and on the client you have to do "./fossil push http://myusername@localhost:8081"

Answer (score 5):

[I can't comment, but...]
You can also add the user credentials when cloning the repository:

```
fossil clone http://username:pass@URL:8080 repository_name
```

I'm the only one working on my projects so I set up auto-sync - whenever I commit I can commit local and send remote in one step [just fossil commit].

Answer (score 2):

See if the following works for you.

```
$ whoami
pc
$ fossil version
This is fossil version 1.34 [62dcb00e68] 2015-11-02 17:35:44 UTC
```

Clone the remote repository (the local username, `pc`, has a namesake account on the remote repository).

```
$ fossil clone http://localhost:8080 bla.fossil
```

What's the remote repository URL for this clone?

```
$ fossil remote-url -R bla.fossil
http://localhost:8080
```

OK, let's specify the remote username; we'll use the same as the local username, `$USER`:

```
$ fossil remote-url -R bla.fossil http://$USER@localhost:8080
password for bla:
remember password (Y/n)? y
```

Let's start working:

```
$ mkdir bla
$ cd bla
$ fossil open ../bla.fossil
```

In the end, commit to your local repository `bla.fossil`. Finally, push to remote:

```
$ fossil push
```

Because `remote-url` now has the username (and you memorized the password when prompted) it should work.